# Calling awscli using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, redis, aws-cli

My main objective is : 1. Accessing redis(elasticache) cluster from NodeJS lambda

I have been trying to figure my way out to access the Redis cluster details using lambda. I have made good progress in this process, however, I am stuck at a point where I need to call awscli using NodeJs Lambda function.

The way I went about figuring out this problem was I first decided to try and pull the details of Elasticache cluster using 'awscli'

Initially, I figured a way out to query and list all clusters

command: aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --show-cache-node-info

Separated the result as per the service we created

command: aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --cache-cluster-id abc-rcache --show-cache-node-info

Further drilled down the command to get the result that I needed i.e the host details for elastic cache.

command: aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --cache-cluster-id abc-rcache --show-cache-node-info | grep Address

Now, my requirement is to invoke the above command(awscli) in a NodeJS lambda, I am finding some results but they are leaning towards python, however, it is not clear how I need to do it in NodeJS(or maybe I am not understanding correctly).

Digging more as i post :)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Regards,
Sameer Varpe

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use elastic cache SDK instead of calling CLI with nodejs.
Everything you can do with cli is also possible with SDK,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElastiCache.html

E.g.,

```
var elasticache = new AWS.ElastiCache();
elasticache.addTagsToResource(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As Kannaiyan recommended, use the SDK. Parsing the output from the CLI in Lambda is problematic. Using the CLI will increasing the running time of Lambda. This may not be a factor in your case just a heads-up.

Comment: Thanks guys will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out the problem with some help from my colleagues using awscli itself and parse the result and get the exact result.

```
    //import { Aws, Options } from 'aws-cli-js';
var awsCli = require('aws-cli-js');
var Options = awsCli.Options;
var Aws = awsCli.Aws; 
//const options = new Options(
//  aws_access_key_id = ID
//aws_secret_access_key = Key2
  /* currentWorkingDirectory */ null
//);


const aws = new Aws();

return aws.command('elasticache describe-cache-clusters --cache-cluster-id abc-rcache --show-cache-node-info').then((data) => {
 console.log(JSON.parse(data.raw).CacheClusters[0].CacheNodes[0].Endpoint.Address);
 console.log(JSON.parse(data.raw).CacheClusters[0].CacheNodes[0].Endpoint.Port);
});
//describe-instances
//awsCli.command('ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-789b3ba7').then(function (data) {
//  console.log('data = ', data); 
//});
```

Thanks Kannaiyan for your response on this :).

~Cheers,
Sameer Varpe